# MS Access design for a helpdesk/customers support form

Tags: microsoft-access

I have seen a nifty program based on php and sql. The program is used for logging computer problems and printing a workorder for a customer. Can someone point me to a free database + form design in Access which I can use and alter a bit?

I could make it partly myself, but I think I would spend most of the time on Stackoverflow and it would take to much time.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if one of the templates provided by MS is helpful for you. Depending on what version of Access/office you are using, maybe [this one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT010142824.aspx#ai:TC010206880|) is something to start from:

Anyway, the list of templates can be viewed [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT010117248.aspx), also for Office 2010 or older.